# Close my js accordion with html link

Tags: javascript

I've got the html links in the top header opening the accordion links, but now I want one of them to close them all. What do I need to add to the js?

http://imip.rvadv.com/index2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets say you want to hide all on click of home which has id home. you need add following code

```
$("#home").click(function(){
  $(".st-open a").click();
  $(window).scrollTop(0); // Added for scrolling top
})
```

Comment: That closes the accordion perfectly, but I also need the entire page to go back to the top.

Comment: modified answer to support scroll top